# Forward selection with BIC for robust regression methods?

Tags: r, regression, model-selection, robust, stepwise-regression

I want to fit a robust linear model to my data using the `rlm` function in `R`.
Is there any function that provides forward model selection in combination with robust methods (I only know the function `stepAIC` for `lm`)? I want to use the BIC as selection criterion.

Comment: Are you commited to using stepwise regression? Maybe you could use the `dredge` function from package MuMIn instead? It calculates BIC of all possible models and can rank them accordingly. Of course that only works with a limited number of regressors.

Comment: Does the glmulti package not work with rlm's?

Answer (score 3):

I would not use stepwise regression. If the number of regressors is limited, I'd calculate the BIC of all possible models:

```
library(MASS)
fit <- rlm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

library(MuMIn)
dredge(fit, rank = "BIC")
#Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
#Global model call: rlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
#---
#Model selection table 
#   (Int) Ptl.Lng  Ptl.Wdt Spl.Wdt Spc df   logLik   BIC  delta weight
#8  1.878  0.7231 -0.59190  0.6401      5  -37.388  99.8   0.00  0.372
#14 2.383  0.7924           0.4249   +  6  -34.919  99.9   0.07  0.359
#16 2.200  0.8499 -0.32960  0.4777   +  7  -32.703 100.5   0.65  0.269
#<...>
#Models ranked by BIC(x)
```

It also handles interactions well:

```
fit1 <- rlm(Sepal.Length ~ .*., data = iris)
dredge(fit1, rank = "BIC")[1:3]
#Global model call: rlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ . * ., data = iris)
#---
#Model selection table 
#   (Int) Ptl.Lng Ptl.Wdt Spl.Wdt Spc Ptl.Lng:Spl.Wdt df  logLik   BIC delta weight
#8  1.878  0.7231 -0.5919  0.6401                      5 -37.388  99.8  0.00  0.366
#14 2.383  0.7924          0.4249   +                  6 -34.919  99.9  0.07  0.353
#46 1.504  1.0540          0.6890   +        -0.08096  7 -32.638 100.4  0.52  0.282
#Models ranked by BIC(x)
```

Of course, I would be wary of combining this kind of model selection with robust regression. I prefer using robust regression if I have some confidence in the underlying model.

Comment: So you would do model selection for the linear model and then fit the robust version?

Comment: No, I would avoid automated model selection if at all possible; in particular, if you are concerned about influential values, which I assume is your reason for wanting to use robust regression.

Comment: Indeed, that is the reason why I use the robust regression. Which method for variable selection and size of the model you prefer?

Comment: As I said, I would want to rely on expert knowledge to decide for an appropriate model, which can then be fit by a robust method.