# Can you extract AIC values in robust linear regression and use these for model selection?

Tags: r, linear-model, aic, robust

I am wondering why is it not possible to extract estimated AIC (and BIC) via 'lmrob()' and 'lmRob()' robust linear regression models (from the 'robustbase' and 'robust' packages, respectively). In this way I can't perform an AIC based model selection.

Example:

```
rob_model<-lmrob(CWM ~ SWB, data = dat, setting="KS2014")
AIC(rob_model)
```

Error message:

```
  Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
      no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "lmrob"
```

Can't find a proper answer to this issue by myself. Is it because comparison of AIC values of robust linear models does not make sense? Apparently you can do that via 'rlm()' function and rank models accordingly (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180323/forward-selection-with-bic-for-robust-regression-methods), for example)

Comment: If you have reason to use robust regression, model selection purely based on statistics is even more dangerous than with non-robust regression models. Also: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-April/070611.html